# flask before request - add exception for specific route

Tags: python, flask

In the `before_request()` function (below), I want to redirect the user to `/login` if they are not yet logged in. Is there a special variable that will give me the current URL that will work as the below example does?

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # the variable current_url does not exist
    # but i want something that works like it
    if (not 'logged_in' in session) and (current_url != '/login'):
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I need to check that the current URL is `/login`, because if I don't the server goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

There are a couple of properties on the request object you can check, documented [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path), `request.path` is probably what you want. Can I suggest [`request.endpoint`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.endpoint) though, so you'll be covered should you decide to route your view to another url, or multiple urls

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'logged_in' not in session and request.endpoint != 'login':
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: I am trying to do something really similar and are indeed trying to use request.endpoint, but what I have discovered is that that property shows up only on two of my routes ('/' and '/about/').

For all other routes, request.endpoint is None and when inspecting the request object, url_rule doesn't even exist?

All my routes are defined the same way with the app.router decorator. Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I needed to add `and request.endpoint != 'static'` to get this working correctly under the dev server of the latest flask dev code

Comment: +1 for checking whether the endpoint of the request is 'login', or else some redirect loop will occur. :-)

Comment: If anyone wonders what the deal with endpoints is, this is a good explanation on Flask routing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262349/593487

Comment: Note, to access the actual function, you can do so using `current_app.view_functions[request.endpoint]`. This way one can implement `@auth_exempt` decorator that'd set an attribute on a view function, and a `before_request` handler that would check for this attribute.

Answer (score 25):

You can use a decorator. Here's an example that shows how to check an API key before specific requests:

```
from functools import wraps

def require_api_key(api_method):
    @wraps(api_method)

    def check_api_key(*args, **kwargs):
        apikey = request.headers.get('ApiKey')
        if apikey and apikey == SECRET_KEY:
            return api_method(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)

    return check_api_key
```

And you can use it with:

```
@require_api_key
```

Comment: from functools import wraps

Comment: what is `api_method ` here ?

Comment: it's the method you want to wrap and check api key.

Comment: I believe the proper terminology is decorator. They're awesome nifty things akin to Java interfaces

Answer (score 12):

Here's an implementation of the accepted answer with [flask-login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
@app.before_request
def require_authorization():
    from flask import request
    from flask.ext.login import current_user

    if not (current_user.is_authenticated or request.endpoint == 'login'):
        return login_manager.unauthorized()
```

Comment: could you please look into this..?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885706/aiohttp-before-request-for-each-api-call