# python flask before_request exclude /static directory

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

Thanks to the answer below, I have a `before_request` function which redirects a user to `/login` if they have not yet logged in:

[flask before request - add exception for specific route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367991/flask-before-request-add-exception-for-specific-route)

Here is a copy of my before_request:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'logged_in' not in session and request.endpoint != 'login':
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Files in my static directory are not being served however unless the user is logged in.

On my `/login` page I am sourcing a css file from the `/static` directory but it can not be loaded because of this `before_request`.

I have deployed this application using apache mod_wsgi and in my apache configuration file I have even included the `/static` directory as the site's DocumentRoot.

How can I add an exception to serve my application's `/static` files without the user logging in, but still use this `before_request` for the routes defined by my flask application?

Comment: How are you trying to source the css file right now ? Can you share some code?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to add an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) or [`AliasMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) directive to your Apache config file (or .htaccess file, should you not have access to the `.conf` files) to ensure that *Apache* serves your static files, rather than Flask.  Make sure that you have provided a [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) to [allow the Apache web server to access your static path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).  (Also, don't forget to restart Apache if you are editing the `.conf` files so your changes will be picked up).

As a temporary stop-gap measure (or to make it easy to work with in development) you could also check to make sure that the string `/static/` is not in [`request.path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path):

```
if 'logged_in' not in session \
    and request.endpoint != 'login' \
    and '/static/' not in request.path:
```

Comment: you were right with both the apache config and the request.path stuff. thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps a little better is `and not request.path.startswith('/static/')` because that way you avoid messing with any routes like `/something-else/static/`

Comment: @Milimetric - except that blueprint static paths start with `/blueprintname/` and then contain `/static` after that ;-)  But you are right, it depends on what you are doing :-)

Answer (score 13):

I think that there is a solution cleaner than checking `request.path`.

```
if 'logged_in' not in session and request.endpoint not in ('login', 'static'):
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the Apache approach, but for a quick fix I the following logic at the start of the before_request() function:

```
if flask.request.script_root == "/static":
  return
```

Comment: `flask.request.script_root` gives me an empty string in `before_request`, while `path` has some value. This does not work for me.