# Flask hit decorator before before_request signal fires

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I'm using Flask and using the before_request decorator to send information about
requests to an analytics system. I'm now trying to create a decorator that would
prevent sending these events on a few routes.

The problem I'm running into is getting my decorator to get called before the before_request
signal gets fired.

```
def exclude_from_analytics(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Before decorated function"
        return func(*args, exclude_from_analytics=True, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

# ------------------------

@exclude_from_analytics
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return make_response('..')

# ------------------------

@app.before_request
def analytics_view(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'exclude_from_analytics' in kwargs and kwargs['exclude_from_analytics'] is True:
       return
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367991/flask-before-request-add-exception-for-specific-route

Comment: That's what we are currently doing but as the number of routes and codebase grows, its definitely not a scalable solution.

Comment: My thought was to have the "exclude_from_analytics" decorator put an attribute on the view function itself, then use the Flask API to get the view function from the endpoint and check the attribute.

Comment: FYI, `app.route()` **must** be the topmost decorator. Otherwise your wrapper function is never used. Right now you have this: `exclude_from_analytics(app.route(index))` - as you can see, the original function is passed to `app.route()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the decorator to simply put an attribute on the function (in my example below, I'm using `_exclude_from_analytics` as the attribute). I find the view function using a combination of [request.endpoint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.endpoint) and [app.view_functions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.view_functions).

If the attribute is not found on the endpoint, you can ignore analytics.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

def exclude_from_analytics(func):
    func._exclude_from_analytics = True
    return func

@app.route('/a')
@exclude_from_analytics
def a():
    return 'a'

@app.route('/b')
def b():
    return 'b'

@app.before_request
def analytics_view(*args, **kwargs):
    # Default this to whatever you'd like.
    run_analytics = True

    # You can handle 404s differently here if you'd like.
    if request.endpoint in app.view_functions:
        view_func = app.view_functions[request.endpoint]
        run_analytics = not hasattr(view_func, '_exclude_from_analytics')

    print 'Should run analytics on {0}: {1}'.format(request.path, run_analytics)

app.run(debug=True)
```

The output (ignoring static files...)

```
Should run analytics on /a: False
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2013 15:55:15] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Should run analytics on /b: True
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2013 15:55:18] "GET /b HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I have not tested to see if this works with blueprints. Additionally, a decorator that wraps and returns a NEW function could cause this to not work since the attribute might be hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation on [@Mark Hildreth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575396/1093087) that does wrap and return a function:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, request, g

app = Flask(__name__)

def exclude_from_analytics(*args, **kw):
    def wrapper(endpoint_method):
        endpoint_method._skip_analytics = True

        @wraps(endpoint_method)
        def wrapped(*endpoint_args, **endpoint_kw):
            # This is what I want I want to do. Will not work.
            #g.skip_analytics = getattr(endpoint_method, '_skip_analytics', False)
            return endpoint_method(*endpoint_args, **endpoint_kw)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

@app.route('/')
def no_skip():
    return 'Skip analytics? %s' % (g.skip_analytics)

@app.route('/skip')
@exclude_from_analytics()
def skip():
    return 'Skip analytics? %s' % (g.skip_analytics)

@app.before_request
def analytics_view(*args, **kwargs):
    if request.endpoint in app.view_functions:
        view_func = app.view_functions[request.endpoint]
        g.skip_analytics = hasattr(view_func, '_skip_analytics')
        print 'Should skip analytics on {0}: {1}'.format(request.path, g.skip_analytics)

app.run(debug=True)
```

The reason why it does not work quite as simply as I expected and hoped has to something do with the Flask context stack and the order in which callbacks are applied. Here is a timeline of method calls (based on some debug statements since removed):

```
$ python test-flask-app.py
# Application Launched
DECORATOR exclude_from_analytics
DECORATOR wrapper
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

# REQUEST: /
DECORATOR app.before_request: analytics_view
> Should skip analytics on /: False
ENDPOINT no_skip
127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2016 16:10:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

# REQUEST: /skip
DECORATOR app.before_request: analytics_view
> Should skip analytics on /skip: True
DECORATOR wrapped
ENDPOINT skip
127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2016 16:12:46] "GET /skip HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I would prefer to set `g.skip_analytics` from within the `wrapped` function. But because that is not called until *after* the `analytics_view` `@app.before_request` hook, I had to follow Mark's example and set the `_skip_analytics` attr on the endpoint method loaded in what I'm calling the **application** (as opposed to **request**) context which gets invoked only at launch.

For more on `flask.g` and app context, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33382823/1093087).