# Flask - How do I exclude a route from app.before_request with decorators?

Tags: python, flask

How do I exclude certain functions from my `app.before_request` function. I know you can check `request.endpoint`, but I would like to have this functionality using decorators. Any ideas?

Comment: May be you can use `before_request_funcs` check out here - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_request_funcs

Comment: And probably another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574694/flask-hit-decorator-before-before-request-signal-fires)

Comment: That second solution should work thank you.

Comment: you are welcome :). Added as a small answer with an explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a solution here already - [Flask hit decorator before before_request signal fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574694/flask-hit-decorator-before-before-request-signal-fires)

What basically you end up doing is to define a normal function where you set the exclusion flag and then add it as decorator to all the routes you do not want to be included in the before_request call and then in your before_request where you check for the presence of that said exclusion flag and do things accordingly.

Comment: The key point to that referenced answer, is that you can get the current view function in `@app.before_request` with `view_func = app.view_functions[request.endpoint]`