# redirect in before_app_request

Tags: python, flask

```
mod = Blueprint('users', __name__, url_prefix='/users')

@mod.route('/welcome')
def www():
    return '<h1>Hello</h1>'

@mod.before_app_request
def before_request():
    return redirect(url_for('www'))
```

This code give me this error:

```
  raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('www', {}, None)
```

If I try this one, I will get an infinite loop redirect in the browser.

```
 return redirect(url_for('users.www'))
```

My question is, how can I redirect the `before_app_request` to another action?

---

**EDIT:** log after changes, Now the redirect works, but the error still exists.

http://sharetext.org/dDje

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way you set this up pretty much every request for this blueprint, including one to `'users.www'` - hence the infinite loop redirect.  You need some kind of conditions so that it would learn not to redirect and load the `/welcome` endpoint.

Also, `url_for('www')` will not work as you intend as you need `.` prefix to reference the current blueprint.  [Check the documentation for `url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for)

Maybe something like:

```
@mod.before_app_request
def before_request():
    if request.endpoint != 'users.www':
        return redirect(url_for('.www'))
```

Do note that you might want to print out the request.endpoint and grab the exact one, I can't remember how they are flask handles/names them internally for blueprints.

Reference: [flask before request - add exception for specific route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367991/flask-before-request-add-exception-for-specific-route)