# flask before_request can't access request variable

Tags: python, flask, logging

I have a simple flask app:

```
def create_app():
    config_name = 'testing_local'

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(CONFIG_BY_NAME[config_name])
    app.url_map.converters['bool'] = BooleanConverter
    @app.before_request
    def incoming_request_logging():
        print(request)
    return app
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined variable 'request'
```

I thought the wrapper included the request object when called?

[In this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367991/flask-before-request-add-exception-for-specific-route), first approved answer seems like the request object is inherited?
Can anyone link me to a full example? How can I retrieve this variable?

Comment: You indeed don't seem to have defined request anywhere.

Comment: @dewDevil added an example of what I mean to help and clarify my issue

Comment: You need to import request module for this to work.

Comment: @dewDevil I'm blind... please make an answer so i can mark it as solved, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess declaring this at top of your program might solve your issue, if I think what you said it is:

```
from flask import request
```